# Hibernate-search search from any indexed entity

Tags: jpa, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate-search for searching data in my Jboss application. I have 3 JPA entity classes that all extend BaseEntity class and each are indexed by Lucene. For example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    public abstract Long getId();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DVD")
public class Dvd extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Field
    private String title;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Field
    private String author;
}
```

Now I would like to search for either DVD title or Book author by wildcard search query and get the result list as List. This is what I have this far:

```
public List<BaseEntity> search(String query, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
    List<BaseEntity> results = null;
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    Query luceneQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term("*", "*" + query + "*"));
    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, BaseEntity.class);
    fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    results = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

But with this I am not getting any results. How is it possible to get this to work or is there even way without using buildQueryBuilder for each entity? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the varargs-style method for the classes, like so:

```
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, DVD.class, Book.class);
```

This is because when Hibernate Search creates the search query, it adds the class name(s) to the query (for the _hibernate_class field, which is the indexed class' name).